# How can I center the HTML date & time inputs' native controls?

Tags: html, css, html-input

If I set the custom height to an `<input type="date" />` element, the native controls (up and down buttons) which appear on hover are aligned to the top of the input instead of the center.

```css
input {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

The same happens with `type="time"` inputs but not with `type="number"`. How can I position these buttons to the center (vertically) of the input?

Comment: use padding instead on height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use `padding` instead `height`**

```css
input {
      padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

**Using `height`**

```css
input {
  height: 40px;
}
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
margin-top: 10px!important;
}



input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
margin-top: 10px!important;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: In some cases I need to set a fixed height not padding, is there any solutions for that then?

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

Sea this one just now i edited.

Comment: the up and down arrow still not center

Comment: yeah I ran the code and it didn't affect the up/down buttons